# How do I restore "standard" text-flow after a page-spanning paracol environment?

Tags: paracol

I am using paracol to print text in columns on facing pages.  Text is printed on the remainder of the first page occupied by a page-spanning paracol environment, but not the second.  How do I print text on both pages after such an environment, so it resumes the verso-to-recto flow that one might expect?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\leavevmode\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage%simply to illustrate the use of paracol on facing pages

\begin{paracol}[2]*{4}

text below

\switchcolumn

text below

\switchcolumn

no text below

\switchcolumn

text on following page --> :-(

\end{paracol}

\blindtext[5]

\end{document}
```

My full document has a non-pagebreaking new chapter after paracol, but I've left it out of the MWE because it seems that paracol's behavior is the same without it.  Moreover, the text within paracol is far more complicated than in the MWE, so it's not feasible to replace it with another environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to store two pages worth of text into a savebox, then split off one page at a time inside another paracol.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\remains}
\newsavebox{\twopagebox}

\begin{document}

\leavevmode\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage%simply to illustrate the use of paracol on facing pages

\begin{paracol}[2]*{4}

text below \thecolumn

\switchcolumn

text below  \thecolumn

\switchcolumn

no text below \thecolumn

\switchcolumn

text on following page \thecolumn

\end{paracol}

\setlength{\remains}{\dimexpr \pagegoal-\pagetotal}% space remaining on page
\setbox\twopagebox=\vbox{\lipsum[1-12]}% two pages of text
\begin{paracol}[1]*{2}
\setbox0=\vsplit\twopagebox to \remains
\unvbox0
\switchcolumn
\setbox0=\vsplit\twopagebox to \remains
\unvbox0
\end{paracol}
\unvbox\twopagebox% print leftovers

\end{document}
```

Comment: Chapters appear to work fine within the savebox.  If I've understood correctly, "twopagebox"  and "remains" are variables, so one can use the same solution later in the document by creating another \newlength and \newsavebox, assigning them non-conflicting names.

Comment: \remains and \twopagebox are reusable and the box is automatically emptied by \unvbox.